# Jquery multiple countdown on page

Tags: jquery, countdown

How to put **multiple countdown timers** on one page, each countdown pointing out to a different period of time, and of course, not reseting on page-refresh?

I'm wondering if there exists a **jQuery** solution for that?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes. Have a look at: http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

Comment: check [Cut & Paste Count down until any date](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/count.shtml), [Cut & Paste Count down until any date (Down-to-the second)](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/count2.shtml) [A Simple JavaScript Countdown](http://www.bellaonline.com/articles/art40292.asp), [JavaScript Countdown/Count-up Timer/Clock/Ticker for Web Pages
](http://www.hashemian.com/tools/javascript-countdown.htm).This one might be helpful [Multiple countdown timers ](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=149460).
Good luck.

Comment: You can run multiple countdown instances with different counters with independent control and fallbacks using [jCounter](http://devingredients.com/jcounter/) Was this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1):

**try this:**

```
<input type="text" id="but1" />
<input type="text" id="but2" />
<input type="text" id="but3" />
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="timer(1)" />
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="timer(2)" />
<input type="button" value="start" onclick="timer(3)" />
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stoptimer(1)" />
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stoptimer(2)" />
<input type="button" value="stop" onclick="stoptimer(3)" />


<script type="text/javascript">
var counts = [];
var xs = [];
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
  counts.push(i*2);
  xs.push(0);
};




function timer(id)
{
  xs[id]=setTimeout("timer("+id+")",1000);
  counts[id]=counts[id]-1;
  document.getElementById("but"+id).value=counts[id];
  if (counts[id] <1){counts[id]=5;}
}

function stoptimer(id)
{
  clearTimeout(xs[id]);
}

</script>
```